# FIR Notch, to delete the frequency in w = pi/2

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

The point is that I'd like to delete the frequency in `w = pi/2`, and  I have the impulsive response which is:

```
h = (1./(pi*(n-alpha)).*(sin(w0*(n-alpha)))-sin(w1*(n-alpha))); %% the impulsive response
```

I've all parameters but the frequency in `w1` is not defined, and I'm wondering if I can cosinder the tollerance I mean; `w1 = pi/+ delta` and `w0 = pi/-delta`, and give a specific value for `delta`, and after delete the frequency in `pi/2`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to provide some code that you've tried and that's not working or at least an attempt to solve the problem yourself. To improve your question you could have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Agreeing with that. It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to design a filter, or understand one?

Generally, this sounds like a filter theory question and not at all like a programming question, so for now it's unclear what you're asking, but it might turn out your question is totally off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Thanx you all! sorry for the late answer, I already solved it.